# How to select iframe using selenium2 if iframe is only having attributes src and style

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to follow a number of methods for accessing iframe like selectFrame("index=1") method and 
selectFrame("//iframe[@src='url path']"). But none of above are letting me access to iframe.

My sample iframe looks like this `<iframe src = "" style = ""></iframe>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SwitchTo() function like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void iframeTest()
    {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:2720/Default.aspx");
        driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtTest"));
        query.SendKeys("abc123");

    }
```

**Edit**

if your wanting to select from a given number of iframes in a page and the only difference is the src then you could use this:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[src=\"test.aspx\"]")));
```

Comment: I want to access iframe using 2nd method, using cssselector but there src is changing dynamically. what's the solution for that?<iframe src="rendermail.jsp?msgid=1397465784-36089929-asdfghi007&amp;time=1397466573109" frameborder="0" width="888" height="1200" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">&lt;/ifram&gt;</iframe>